# Detecting and then reversing a number within a string

Tags: javascript, string, split, right-to-left

Lone developer here. Looking for some ideas how I can detect numbers in a string and reverse the characters of said numbers. For example given the string:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor 345 sit $4.50 amet,78% consectetur 45.60%adipisicing elit'
```

The resulting string would be:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor 543 sit 05.4$ amet,%87 consectetur %06.54adipisicing elit'
```

The trick is identifying the whole number segment which may include currency symbol, percentage symbol, period or comma decimal separators, thousand separators. I'd like to be able to reverse the sub section of a string relating to, and being a number.

Ideas?

Comment: Purely out of interest - why do you want to do this?

Comment: It's a strange use case but it has to do with right-to-left text, splitting a selection and displaying numbers in their correct orientation.

Comment: Oh jeese! Years back we had to implement our own right-to-left parsing for Hebrew in ActionScript. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a good job for a regular expression:

```
var result = input.replace(/\$?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?%?/g,
                           function(s) { return s.split('').reverse().join(''); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6A3Nn/2/

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the RegEx to me so I can expand on it. For example given the string '.1234' it is not resulting '.4321'.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replace(/[0-9.$%]+/g, function(x) {
    return x.split('').reverse().join('')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TjB28/5/)

Comment: for some reason he wants the % and $ to go to the other end too. You'll need to add those too I think.

Answer (score 0):

A bit crude but should work.

```
function reverseNumInStr(str){
  var wordArray = str.split(' ');

  var newList = [];
  wordArray.forEach(function(word){
    var newWord = word.replace("$","").replace(".","").replace("%","").replace(",","");

    var num = parseFloat(newWord);

    if(!isNaN(num)){
      newList.push(word);
    }else{
      newList.push(reverseStr(word));
    }

  });

  return newList.join(" ");
}

function reverseStr(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = input.replace(/[0-9.$%]+/g, function(oneway) {
    return oneway.split("").reverse().join("");
  });
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OB6R0qIYcJ58BNV2g7Dm?p=preview)**

Given below are some useful references

- [Excellent RegEx Editor](http://www.regexr.com/)
- [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)